# How do I convert a date of the format DDMMMYYYY into a db storable date

Tags: php, datetime

Hi guys my application parses text files where date values are stored in the format: DDMMMYYYY eg: 12MAR2009.

I noticed that inserting this value as it is into a database datetime value doesn't work at all. How do I convert this into a datetime value which can be entered into a database. My application is in php.

Comment: Most DBMS have functions to parse dates from strings. Have you considered leaving this task to the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$timestamp = strtotime("12MAR2009");

...

INSERT INTO my_table (..., timestamp) VALUES (..., FROM_UNIXTIME($timestamp))
```

The PHP function [`strtotime()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) will take almost any string containing a date/time value, and convert it to a unix timestamp.

The MySQL function [`FROM_UNIXTIME()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime) will take a unix timestamp and convert it to MySQL's datetime format.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this should convert your date into [MySQL's DATETIME format](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/datetime.html):

```
$date = new DateTime('12MAR2009', new DateTimeZone('America/New_York'));
$mysql_date = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

You can use `strtotime()`, but timezone handling with it is kind of a pain.

Comment: +1 for mentioning time zones. Dates / datetimes should always be saved with time zone info. Otherwiese, both users moving around, and moving around of the servers are potential sources of errors.

Comment: Currently my application revolves around basic UTC time - your point is valid should I require keeping a log of timings specific to each user based upon where they are. I'll keep that in mind in another project - thanks again.